# Costumize button_html in JsPsych

Tags: javascript, jspsych

Does anyone know how to specify the button_html, so it also allows for the participant to press 'r' on the keyboard to repeat the sound/trial? R doesn't need to be shown as a button on the screen it only needs to be possible to press it to repeat.

This is the code I've used:

```
  var sound_trial = {
    type: jsPsychAudioButtonResponse,
    stimulus: 'sound/Centrifuge.mp3',
    choices: ['img/test1.png', 'img/test2.png', 'img/test3.png', 'img/test4.png', 'r'],
    prompt: "<p>Hvilket billede passer til ordet?</p>",
    button_html: '<img src="%choice%" /></button>',
    name: 'soundtrial',
    on_finish: function (data) {
      jsPsych.data.addProperties({ sound: data.response });
      //jsPsych.data.displayData();
    }
  };

  var loop_node = {
    timeline: [sound_trial],
    loop_function: function(data){
        if(jsPsych.pluginAPI.compareKeys(data.values()[0].response, 'r')){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
  };

  timeline.push(loop_node);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use [keydown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) to catch the event when R is pressed and then call the function, which repeats the sound/trial.

Comment: Or, alternatively, use the [audio-keyboard-response](https://www.jspsych.org/7.3/plugins/audio-keyboard-response/) plugin.